# Как сделать так, чтобы после перезагрузи страницы загруженный файл оставался в input?

Tags: php, файлы, post, upload

Как сделать так, чтобы после перезагрузи страницы файл оставался в `input`?

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="upload">
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: по-моему этот атрибут не доступен для записи из соображений безопасности, иначе можно было бы взять любой файл из системы, пользователю придется самому выбирать файлы

Comment: Хмм... А что если использовать кэш ?

Comment: очень сомневаюсь. прям очень. как вариант: грузи файлы сразу после выбора и веди их список на странице, в сессию пиши пути(либо любым другим способом, я писал в куку уникальный путь и смотрел наличие в нём файлов) и при формировании страницы выводи все загруженные файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Это противоречет безапасности.

Так как через это возможность можно подстовлять любой файл на машине пользователя, сответсвенно можно скачать любой файл пользователя. А это не возможно сделать.